# morea-run-local.sh not watching src/morea directory

Tags: morea-framework

If I change files in the `src/` or, for example, `src/css/` folder, the server regenerates the site automatically. However, if I modify code in `src/morea/`, there's no regeneration. Any idea what I've done wrong? [Here](https://github.com/bruab/cs294_fall2015) is my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Unfortunately, you've done nothing wrong, that is now the "correct" behavior in Jekyll.

Long answer: Morea sites tell Jekyll in the _config.yml file to exclude the morea/ directory from normal processing (so that the Morea plugin can process all of the files in that directory in a custom manner).  A few releases ago, Jekyll changed the default behavior of the `--watch` parameter to the `jekyll serve` command (which is what is invoked in morea_run_local.sh). Before, the `--watch` parameter would tell Jekyll to monitor all directories (even excluded ones) and regenerate the site when any of those files were touched.  Currently, the default behavior for `--watch` is to not monitor excluded directories. As a result, you now have to kill the morea_run_local.sh process and restart to see your changes to the morea/ directory.

While the current behavior seems reasonable for Jekyll sites in general, it's not optimal for Morea sites, and I've been in touch with the Jekyll developers about the possibility of creating a parameter to customize the behavior of `--watch` so that the morea/ directory could be excluded but still watched.  Hopefully we'll get that done in some future release.

Answer (score 0):

It seem there's now a ./morea-watch.rb scripts that just solves it.
See: http://morea-framework.github.io/userguide.html#morea-watch